# How to test devise mail delivery with devise, rspec, capybara, and mailspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, mailer

I'm trying to test if devise is sending out confirmation emails. This is becomming to be a bit of a challenge to me because, the tests use a different environment in Rails and I'm not quite sure if I'm going the right route. 
Here's my rspec test.

```
describe "Sign up:", :type => :feature do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

    visit root_path

    click_link "Sign Up"

    fill_in "Name", :with => @user.name
    fill_in "Email", :with => @user.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => @user.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => @user.password

    click_button "Sign up"
end

describe "user gets a confirmation email" do
 subject { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last }
 it { is_expected.to deliver_to(@user.email) }
end
```

This is the message when I run the spec.

```
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to deliver_to(@user.email) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `perform_deliveries' for nil:NilClass
```

I would like to test this feature, but can Rails send out emails in a test environment? If so what kind of code makes this type of code pass? I have the mailer set up to sendgrid, so I can show that as well. User's of Devise are set to confirmable, so a confirmation email is supposed to be coming out.

Comment: The issue might be that your mailer is delivering asynchronously and the delivery is actually performed after your expectation. I.e. a `sleep 1` before your expectation might solve your problem (this is widely considered an anti-pattern though)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this set in your  you have this set in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

In your spec, you can also just test that `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` has changed:

```
describe "Sign up:", :type => :feature do
  # ...

  it "sends a confirmation email" do
    expect {
      click_button "Sign up"

      # for example. the point is to wait for the AJAX response
      page.find('p.thanks', text: 'Thanks for signing up')
    }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size }.by(1)
  end
end
```

Similarly, if you're using Sidekiq, you can instead check that the number of Sidekiq jobs went up.

Personally, I'd save testing the specifics of the email for a unit test, and use the feature test to make sure that everything's wired together.

Also, if you want to verify manually that the emails are getting sent, [Mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write in test environment:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I hope it will help You!